# How can I change the data source of a chart in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a word document that is filled with charts. All of these charts pull data from one excel file. This excel file is stored on our company network, so my worry is that when I send the word document externally, the link will break and data will not be able to be displayed in the charts.

Because of this, I want to change the source of the data to be stored within the word document (like how it is if you create a chart in word by simply pressing the insert chart button).

Let me know if you want any clarification on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you are not sharing the Excel file externally? Depending on the size of your Word file and the amount of labor involved (how many charts, how often you share the file, etc.), perhaps it would be easier to paste your charts into the Word file as images. However, if you're looking for an approach where the data and chart remain linked, you might be better off trying to get the two into a single file (easier to manage than one). Excel is more suited for this than Word.

Answer (score 0):

In industries, documents are often kept on a network server. it may be across the country or out of the world.

If you are creating documents that include many graphs, the common practice is to link those graphs and to store the graphs on a network server where they are accessible by everyone.

When linking to graph over the network, Word keeps track of the graph's location using a UNC (Universal Naming Convention).In examining the old and new addresses, you may have notice that the only thing that changed was the name of the server.

*To change all the links in your document to reflect the new server name, follow these steps.*

1. Open the document in which you want to change 
   the links.
2. Change to `Draft view`.
3. Press `Alt+F9` to show field codes.
4. Press `Ctrl+H` to displays `Find and Replace
   dialog box`.
5. In the `Find box`, enter the portion of the 
   link you want to change.
6. In the `Replace box`, enter the new portion of 
   the link.
7. Finish with `Replace All` then press `Ctrl+A` 
   & `F9`.

*Word will update all the fields in the document, including those links you just changed.*